# MiKTeX installation on multiple computers: how to synchronize them?

Tags: pdftex, packages, miktex

I've installed basic-miktex-2.9.7031-x64 on my Windows 10 computer and started to develop a solution for a newsletter.

This newsletter should be produced on the Windows computers of other people and the same basic-miktex-2.9.7031-x64 was installed on two of them.
Then I ran the newsletter transformation from a tex file to a PDF on both additional computers, all additional packages required by the used class were installed.

Then, using the MiKTeX Console in Admin mode, I've checked for the same Languages settings and I ran an Update of all installed packages on all three computers. My assumption was: all three systems should be in the same state.

Unfortunately the produced PDFs are different (TeXworks was used in all cases):

- the size of the PDF was on my computer 584kB, on both other computers 562kB
- on my computer the used san serif font looks perfect, on both other
  computers the font is a bit blurred.

Is there a way to record which packages and fonts (with version) are used for such a tex-PDF transformation? Can all the installed packaged and fonts (with version) be written to a log?

Comment: There is already a log-file, check your document folder.

Comment: Filtered the 2500 lines of the log file and got 200 lines of package and font related information. (It showed different fonts are used.)

Comment: If you like my answer and it was helpful, please consider [upvoting](http://tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up) (by clicking on the arrows next to the score) and/or marking it as the [accepted answer](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852) (by clicking on the checkmark ✓). Please see that is the way here to say "Thank you for your help"!

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are some issues you have:

1. Use the same installer and repository (perhaps a local one) to install MiKTeX. You can install as admin (could bring some other issues) or as user (only that user can use MiKTeX) or you can try the portable version (I have not tested). Depending on your needs make your choise, but I would suggest user installation.
2. To get really the same installation make sure the operating system (Windows) of all used computers is the same, with the same service packs for windows installed! That is important, because the MiKTeX installer **can react in different ways for different OS versions**!
3. Check if the several computers contains other programs, which have installed own fonts on the computer (for example Corel Draw) you can see in the font table. If that is the case make sure that only fonts are used in the newsletter which are installed on **each** computer...
4. You did not show us the short example code of that newsletter, so I can not see, if you are using packages or code using fall-back-fonts if an wanted font is not installed. So make sure that all computers use the same engine to compile the code (for example `pdflatex`) and that there are no fallbacks possible with the given tex code.
5. Please make sure you have installed the same pdf viewer in the same version in all computers, because different pdf viewer (version) can show the compiled pdf in different way ...

If the tex code compiled on the several computers results in different pdf sizes (as you mentioned: "584kB, on both other computers 562kB") it could be that different font versions are included in the document as you already mentioned ("san serif font looks perfect, on both other computers the font is a bit blurred"; BTW: Your question would be  clearer, if you had named the used font :-).

If there would only the different view of the font (blurred or not) that could be caused by different pdf viewer, but different pdf size not ...